# "Tree view" for wp_dropdown_categories() markup

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, user-interface

I'm using `wp_dropdown_categories()` to generate a `select` box of hierarchical categories.  By default, the select box is just a huge list of indented categories:

[image]

This works fine until the number of categories grows beyond 50 or 100.  On our site, we are *far* beyond that.

Analyzing the HTML source generated by `wp_dropdown_categories()` shows that the hierarchy is expressed nicely using the "level-x" class:

[image]

This suggests that it would be possible to reformat the dropdown to more accurately reflect the hierarchical nature of the data.  **Is there a WP/jQuery plugin that will allow us to transform this long, unwieldy dropdown into something more managable, using a tree view?**  The best option I've found seems to be [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=bootstrap&dir=ltr&pitem=Basic):

[image]

Unfortunately, this plugin has several "issues", the most problematic is that it functions on `<input />` elements, instead of `<select />` elements (so it isn't very compatible with the output of `wp_dropdown_categories()`).

Comment: And your specific question is?

Comment: The last two paragraphs pose the question/issue.  The actual question is bolded.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, your actual question is off-topic. I'm sorry but asking for recommendatuib fir third party product is off-topic here. See the [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).